# React state not updating after a post request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, react-redux, axios

I'm trying to send a post request to my backend with axios, and my backend gets the values with no problem, but I want to set a state of (sent) to true when the post request is "successfully sent", I put the `setSent(true)` in the `.then()` after the axios request. but when I send the request the state isn't updated! what could be the problem? backend gets the values and works fine though... see code bellow:

```
const submitHandler = () => {
    axios
      .post(
        "/sendFeedback",
        qs.stringify({
          name,
          email,
          text,
        })
      )
      .then(() => {
        setSent(true)            // doesn't work (the state is still false)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        err && setError(true)  // works just fine!
      })
  }
```

Comment: How's your component updating the state?

Comment: When and how are you checking the state value?

Comment: @k-wasilewski through the react dev tools

Comment: @ShivamJha sorry I didn't quite get what you mean?

Comment: How you are using `useState()` will definitely help in solving this problem. Moreover, react state changes are `asynchronous`. So, you need `useEffect()` tocheck for a change in state, and then work accordingly.

Comment: You check the value of your state in react dev tools, but where is initialized your state in the first place ? Can you provide us  with the entire component ? We expect to see something like : const [sent, setSent] = useState(false)

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
const submitHandler = async () => await axios ...
```

because it's asynchronous process and returns a promise.